# What does "paper rejected provisionally" mean?

Tags: journals, peer-review

I submitted a paper to a prestigious control journal. The editor provided the following review:

> The decision is that your contribution cannot be accepted for publication in [the journal] in its present form. It needs substantial revision in order to possibly become publishable. Overall the decision is **paper rejected provisionally**.

The editor has invited me to revise and resubmit.

Is "paper rejected provisionally" equivalent to "major revision" ?

Will you advise me to politely inquire the editor about it so that there is no confusion. I mean before revising I want to be sure that there is some chance that the paper can be accepted if I incorporate the reviewer's comments.

Comment: Why are you suppressing the journal name?

Comment: @Walter: Sometimes back I wrote a post mentioning journal name. I was told by admin/moderators that this site cannot comment on a  particular journal and suggested me to ask general question.

Comment: In case of this post, mentioning the journal name does not render the question non-general, though.

Comment: @Walter Does it add anything, though? Someone choosing not to include the journal name doesn't seem like a big deal.

Comment: Including the journal name is inappropriate.  It could allow a reviewer who happens to read this to identify a blinded submission, for example.

Comment: Journals use different rejection resubmission concepts.  It is whatever they say it is.

Comment: Could a journal be trying to game its statistics (about how quickly it accepts papers for example) by doing this?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm if a journal wanted to game its statistics, then couldn't the editor just order up a bunch of low quality papers (computers can generate them), submit them, and promptly reject them.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've seen language like this before as well, and feel that it is unnecessarily confusing. Usually, what I have found is that it's effectively equivalent to "Major Revision."  Here is a good heuristic for distinguishing:

- If they give you a date that they'd like to see the revised version by, then it's equivalent to "Major Revision."
- If they don't give you a date, then you've been rejected, but they really are inviting you to submit a better version when you are ready.

Comment: They have given deadline. Also, there is a resubmission link given in the original submission account.

Comment: @RIchardWilliams Then it's just an awkward phrasing of a request for major revision.

Comment: As I said in [this answer of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66009/is-it-normal-for-the-manuscript-submission-date-to-change-from-the-original-subm/66016#66016) there can be nuances to the awkward phrasing including who reviews the new submission and the submission date.

Comment: @jakebeal:Thanks for the earlier suggestion. Please suggest on the edit at the end of the post.

Comment: @jakebeal: I think one reasonable explanation of "reject provisionally" phrase is that "your contribution cannot be accepted for publication in [the journal] in its present form". provisionally means that the paper is rejected in its *present form*.

Comment: @RIchardWilliams I completely agree with you --- it's just that it's a fairly convoluted phrasing compared to a request for major revision, and causes confusion of the sort you experienced.

Answer (score 5):

> It needs **substantial** revision in order to possibly become publishable

That's sounds the same as "major revision" to me.

> Is "paper rejected provisionally" equivalent to "major revision" ?

You're simply concentrating on the last thing written, not the part about "substantial revision", which is unambiguous.  All the "provisional" part is saying is that they're open to re-submission after a big rewrite and are not completely rejecting it (and you).  I'd actually consider it as a mildly encouraging choice of words.

Comment: "You're simply concentrating on the last thing written" Because that's the only part he doesn't understand! And I'd say that "rejected provisionally" is a very _discouraging_ form of words. "Rejected" means "we don't your paper", whereas the intended message seems to be, "If you improve your paper, we might accept it."

Comment: @StephenG: What about the above comment ?

Answer (score 0):

As an invited reviewer to some journals, my advice is to prepare a letter detailing a response to each comment and a major revision of the paper. The comments should direct you to what needs revising. Aim to do this as soon as you can. If there's a date, you must submit by that date. If there isn't, turn it around within 1 month. Good luck!